# Error when I run Php artisan serve

Tags: php, laravel, xampp

After I installed the right XAMPP (I installed XAMPP -VM before). I tried to run php artisan serve, this is what I get

> PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '?' in /Users/nelz/Lara53/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/helpers.php on line 233
>
> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '?' in /Users/nelz/Lara53/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/helpers.php on line 233

And now my Laravel project is not running on serve.

Comment: Looks like you've got the wrong version of PHP. Laravel requires PHP 7

Comment: Did you look at line 233 to see what is there?

Comment: @Phil which is wrong version of XAMPP?